# Unable to log debug messages to the system log in Python

Tags: python, macos, logging, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.4 on Mac OSX. I have the following code to setup a logger:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(PROGRAM_NAME)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER.propagate = False

LOGGER_FH = logging.FileHandler(WORKING_DIR + "/syslog.log", 'a')
LOGGER_FH.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER_FH.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
LOGGER.addHandler(LOGGER_FH)

LOGGER_SH = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/var/run/syslog',
                                       facility=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_USER)
LOGGER_SH.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOGGER_SH.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
LOGGER.addHandler(LOGGER_SH)
```

The `FileHandler` works perfectly, and I'm able to see all expected messages at all logging levels show up in the log. The `SysLogHandler` doesn't work correctly. I'm unable to see any `LOGGER.info()` or `LOGGER.debug()` messages in the syslog output. I can see error and warning messages, but not info or debug. Even tweaking the `/etc/syslog.conf` file has no effect (even after explicitly reloading the syslog daemon with launchctl). What am I missing here ?

Comment: are you sure you have write permissions to that file?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget To which file are you referring ? The syslog.log file appended to by the FileHandler which I've stated is working just fine, or the /var/run/syslog socket to which some of the messages (but not all) are getting logged by syslog ? Clearly permissions aren't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try: address='/dev/log'

It's a bit confusing from the doc, but "address" is expected to be a unix domain socket, not a file.